# bootstrap carousel passing data between Panels

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

Please can someone give me a hint over my question below. Thanks.

I'm trying to create dynamic Bootstrap Carousel panels. 
Basically i have two items in carousel and based on the button clicked on the first panel, I want to dynamically load the content in the Second Panel. below is the sample.

http://jsfiddle.net/sure2win/T4zSb/

HTML

```html
   <div id="ismdb" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false" data-ride="carousel">
     <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
       <h3>First Panel</h3> <br>
       <a href="#ismdb" data-slide-to="1" class="btn btn-primary">click1</a>
       <a href="#ismdb" data-slide-to="1" class="btn btn-primary">click2</a>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
       <h3>Second Panel </h3><br>
       <a href="#ismdb" data-slide-to="0" class="btn btn-primary">Previous</a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```css
.carousel, .item{
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#f0f0f0;
    border:1px solid #f0f0f0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Based on whether clicked on "Click1" or "Click2" on First Panel, I want to load the Second panel with text "Second Panel - Click1" or "Second Panel - Click2".

One option could be setting a global variable on click of the buttons, not so impressive option though. Any better ideas for passing data between Panels of Carousel?. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solutions first - why not add a third panel?

```html
<div id="ismdb" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <h3>First Panel</h3> <br/>
            <a href="#ismdb" data-slide-to="1" class="btn btn-primary">click1</a>
            <a href="#ismdb" data-slide-to="2" class="btn btn-primary">click2</a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <h3>Second Panel - Click 1</h3><br/>
            <a href="#ismdb" data-slide-to="0" class="btn btn-primary">Previous</a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <h3>Second Panel - Click 2</h3><br/>
            <a href="#ismdb" data-slide-to="0" class="btn btn-primary">Previous</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### [Demo in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/T4zSb/2/)

---

If you really needed to, you could implement your own `data-slide-to` functionality so you could trap the item that raised the event.  Replace `data-slide-to` with `data-custom-slide-to`.

Then use your own implementation to move the carousel by handling click events.  Here's a clone of the essential parts of `data-slide-to` in our own implementation:

```js
$('.carousel [data-custom-slide-to]').click(function () {     
    var $carousel = $($(this).attr('href'));
    var newIndex = $(this).data('custom-slide-to');
    $carousel.carousel(newIndex);      
});
```

Then add whatever code you'd like to update the new slide. For example:

```js
var buttonText = $(this).html();
var slide = $carousel.find(".item")[newIndex];
$("h4", slide).html("From - " + buttonText);
```

#### [Demo in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/T4zSb/4/)

Comment: Thanks Kyle, nice solutions. Solution 1: Basically i have hundreds of such buttons in first panel, so cannot have that many panels. But the second Solution of custom event seems perfect for my requirement..nice thought. Please let me know for any other solution too :).. Thank you.